# How to animate a subview based on Picker-selection in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-animation

Trying to understand animations/transitions in SwiftUI, but I'm totally lost. Everything regarding animations seems to be triggered by a bool state-variable.

How would I animate the "Text()" in my if-else-blocks in the code below? Say I want to slide them from the top and also animate the opacity with easeIn while they slide down.

I have tried withAnimation on the Picker and set .transition() on the Text(). But either it's not working (without errors) or I get compiler errors.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var sel: Int = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            Picker(selection: $sel) {
                Text("Choose an option").tag(0)
                Text("Option 1").tag(1)
                Text("Option 2").tag(2)
            } label: {
                Text("Picker")
            }
            
            if sel == 1 {
                
                Text("You picked option 1")
                    .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                    .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20).fill(.gray))
                
            } else if sel == 2 {
                
                Text("You picked option 2")
                    .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                    .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20).fill(.gray))
                
            }
            
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you're switching content and you want to have an animated transition, it often works well to use a `ZStack`. Here's your example with the transition added:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var sel: Int = 0

    var body: some View {
        VStack {

            Picker(selection: $sel) {
                Text("Choose an option").tag(0)
                Text("Option 1").tag(1)
                Text("Option 2").tag(2)
            } label: {
                Text("Picker")
            }
            ZStack {
                if sel == 1 {

                    Text("You picked option 1")
                        .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                        .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20).fill(.gray))
                        .transition(.move(edge: .top).combined(with: .opacity))

                } else if sel == 2 {

                    Text("You picked option 2")
                        .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                        .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20).fill(.gray))
                        .transition(.move(edge: .top).combined(with: .opacity))

                }
            }
            .animation(.easeIn(duration: 1), value: sel)
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```