# How can I change the direction of the page transition animation?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

When I tap on the navigation link on ContentView1 I want ContentView2 to slide in from the **left** rather than from the right.

So, I want to override the default.

I have not been able to find a solution which works with Swift 5.

The code I'm using is as follows:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView1: View {

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: ContentView2()) {
                Text("Hello, World!")
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("One")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView2: View {

    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World #2!")
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can change the direction of the transition that the native navigation provides. Sliding in from the left is what you get when navigating **back** and that is the way Apple wants it to be.

Comment: There is no native way supported directly by Apple for this. However this might be something you could try out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76658552/how-to-override-default-behaviour-of-navigationview-and-navigationstack-in-swift

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thank you everybody who took the time to answer.

It seems this behaviour isn't supported by default in swift 5.

I will need to rethink how I implement the screen.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in a comment, I don't think you can change the direction of the transition that the native navigation provides. Sliding in from the left is what you get when navigating **back** and that is the way Apple wants it to be.

However, there might be times when you want to launch an app with a nested context pre-loaded, in which case, navigating back would be a valid option. One way to do this is to use a `NavigationStack` with a `path`.

Here is how your example could be adapted to work this way:

```swift
enum NavDestination {
    case view1
    case view2
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var navPath: [NavDestination] = [.view1]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $navPath) {
            ContentView2()
                .navigationDestination(for: NavDestination.self) { destination in
                    switch destination {
                    case .view1: ContentView1()
                    case .view2: ContentView2()
                    }
                }
                .navigationBarTitle("Two")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView1: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
            .font(.largeTitle)
            .bold()
    }
}

struct ContentView2: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink("Hello, World #2!", value: NavDestination.view1)
    }
}
```

[image: Animation]

Alternatively, you could abandon the native navigation and build your own context switcher, then you can use any transitions you like. It often works well to use a `ZStack` for this, as illustrated in the answer to [How to animate a subview based on Picker-selection in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76468307/20386264).